# How to solve a sudoku such that by swapping any two adjacent sub grids I still get a valid answer?

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix, swap, sudoku

I'm given a n^2 * n^2 grid with a few numbers filled in it. I need to fill in the remaining grid using the basic sudoku rules along with one more additional condition which is to ensure that if I swap any 2 adjacent subgrids(n*n) then my overall grid(sudoku) still valid. I'm using the backtracking technique to solve it. But I'm not able to satisfy the additional condition.

```
1 2 | 3 4
3 4 | 1 2
---------
2 1 | 4 3
4 3 | 2 1

2 1 | 3 4
4 3 | 1 2
---------
1 2 | 4 3
3 4 | 2 1
```

Here on swapping the top left box with the bottom left box I still got the answer. Similarly it should be possible if we swap any the boxes side by side or top and bottom if they're adjacent.

Kindly help me. Here is the code for the backtracking approach taken from www.geeksforgeeks.org

```
 bool SolveSudoku(int grid[N][N])
{
    int row, col;

    if (!FindUnassignedLocation(grid, row, col))
       return true;

    for (int num = 1; num <= 9; num++)
    {
        if (isSafe(grid, row, col, num))
        {
            grid[row][col] = num;

            if (SolveSudoku(grid))
                return true;

            grid[row][col] = UNASSIGNED;
        }
    }
    return false; // this triggers backtracking
}

bool FindUnassignedLocation(int grid[N][N], int &row, int &col)
{
    for (row = 0; row < N; row++)
        for (col = 0; col < N; col++)
            if (grid[row][col] == UNASSIGNED)
                return true;
    return false;
}

bool UsedInRow(int grid[N][N], int row, int num)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < N; col++)
        if (grid[row][col] == num)
            return true;
    return false;
}

bool UsedInCol(int grid[N][N], int col, int num)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < N; row++)
        if (grid[row][col] == num)
            return true;
    return false;
}

bool UsedInBox(int grid[N][N], int boxStartRow, int boxStartCol, int num)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
            if (grid[row+boxStartRow][col+boxStartCol] == num)
                return true;
    return false;
}

bool isSafe(int grid[N][N], int row, int col, int num)
{
    return !UsedInRow(grid, row, num) &&
           !UsedInCol(grid, col, num) &&
           !UsedInBox(grid, row - row%3 , col - col%3, num);
}
void printGrid(int grid[N][N])
{
    for (int row = 0; row < N; row++)
    {
       for (int col = 0; col < N; col++)
             printf("%2d", grid[row][col]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

How do I incorporate that condition into this.First of all please let me know if it is possible to solve through backtracking.The upperbound of "n" is 30.

Comment: swapping boxes is not valid. you are allowed to swap single rows or columns within boxes. you can also swap boxes row complete or column complete. rows and columns must containe the very same elements (in different order) after the swap

Answer (score 0):

Given a valid sudoku solution, and two sub-grids `A` and `B` in it that are one above the other (resp. besides the other), you can swap `A` and `B` if and only if they have the same elements (in different orders) on each of their rows (resp.columns). (i.e. `sort(A[i, :])==sort(B[i, :]` for all i in 1..n).

So all you need to do is add some constraints reflecting that:

- when you want to put value `a` in `A[i, j]` (`A` being a subgrid), consider `A`'s neighbors. Given a neighbor `B` above or below `A`, the move is invalid if `a` is already in `B`, in a different row than `i`
- likewise for A's horizontal neighbors (with columns)

So in practice you just need to extend `isSafe()` with a few more constraints :) .

It should actually run faster than without the constraint for big values of n, since you'll explore less of your tree.

**EDIT**

I would add functions UsedInNeighborsWrongRow (rep. column), that can for instance be this:

```
bool UsedInNeighborsWrongRow(int grid[N][N], int boxStartRow, int boxStartCol, int rowIdw, int num) 
{
    for (int row = 0; row < N; row++)
        if (row != rowIdx)
            for (int col = 0; col < N; col++)
                if (grid[row+boxStartRow][col+boxStartCol] == num)
                    return true;    
    return false;
}
```

and call them for each neighbor in `isSafe`:

```
bool isSafe(int grid[N][N], int row, int col, int num)
{
    bool OKForSwapping = !UsedInNeighborsWrongRow(grid, neighbor1_row, neighbor1_col, row, num);
    if (there is a 2nd vertical neighbor) 
        OKForSwapping &=!UsedInNeighborsWrongRow(grid, neighbor2_row, neighbor2_col, row, num);
    OKForSwapping &=!UsedInNeighborsWrongColumn(grid, neighbor3_row, neighbor3_col, col, num);
    if (there is a 2nd horizontal neighbor) 
        OKForSwapping &=!UsedInNeighborsWrongColumn(grid, neighbor4_row, neighbor4_col, row, num);
    return !UsedInRow(grid, row, num) &&
               !UsedInCol(grid, col, num) &&
               !UsedInBox(grid, row - row%N , col - col%N, num) &&
               OKForSwapping;
}
```

It is lengthy but I'm not sure you can do much better, the sudoku structure is better suited for the other constraints than this one...

WARNING: You should replace 3 by N in your function `UsedInBox` and in `isSafe`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the catch. But don't you it's becoming too lengthy that way? I mean here is the code where I'm checking only for top and bottom boxes.I've added 2 more parameters(row & col) in the UsedinBox function.Just tell me if I'm proceeding the right way?http://ideone.com/LbWfZz

Comment: @Impromptu_Coder I've made some edits. I think it's less clean (although maybe a bit faster) to do it in the same function / loops than the other checks, but the method is right.

Comment: @Impromptu_Coder did it work fine in reasonable time ?